# Faking google api client login

Tags: ruby, tdd, google-api-ruby-client

After much struggle I finally got a hybrid flow to work for my login using the Google Api Ruby Client.

Now I started to verify that my login still works as it used to do when I used OpenId. However, all my tests that fake a login with OpenId have now broken.

I used to login using OmniAuth which had a "test mode". However I removed that dependency in order to use the new login method.

So how would I go about to make sure my tests are logged in for the purpose of testing the rest of the functionality?

I based my code on the example given in the quickstart at the goolge documentation: https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/ruby

Comment: Are you talking about testing your application login (OmniAuth) or your Google API calls? For the Google API, I would just mock the whole `client` object. Then you can `allow(client).to_receive(:login).and_return(true)`.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm not using OmniAuth :) I'm using Google own client straight up.

Comment: Are you trying to allow people to sign into your site using their Google account? In that case use OmniAuth. If you are trying to access the Google API (for calendars, search, drive, etc.) then use the google-api-client ruby gem.

Comment: I wanted to use the new openid connect flow. When I wrote the login omniauth didn't have a good plugin for it. But yes, Omniauth has better support for tests, and seems to be the defacto standard.